# How to connect with C#/.NET 4.0 Client to Web Service providing WSDL 2.0

Tags: c#, wsdl, soap-client

I have an SOAP Service exposing a WSDL 2.0 descriptor. I tried to find a way to connect with C# to it using WSDL.EXE / SVCUTIL.EXE - but both of them reject the WSDL.

The WSDL is valid and is accessible with PHP SOAP clients.

Comment: We could use some more information. Ideally a link to the WSDL you're trying to use, or at least what error message you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET currently has no support for WSDL 2.0.

Comment: That is bad news. :( Maybe Microsoft will implement it in future.

Comment: I suggest you make a request for it at http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio. After you do, you should post the link to your suggestion here. That way, people reading your question can vote on the Connect suggestion.